# Registry with full permission

Tags: permissions, registry, admin, nsis

I am trying to give full permission for a registry in nsis but its not working. Below is a sample code.

```
WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Demo\" "mydemo" "abc"
AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Demo\" "PC116\Users" "FullAccess"
```

I tried doing it in a windows XP PC. I tried using REGINI using a vbscript which gives full permission for user "Everyone".
So can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AccessControl plugin only supports the short HKEY names.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define StringSID_BUILTIN_Users S-1-5-32-545

WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Demo\" "mydemo" "abc"
AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Demo\" "(${StringSID_BUILTIN_Users})" "FullAccess"
pop $0
${If} $0 != "ok"
    pop $1
    DetailPrint $0>$1 ; In your case: "error>Bad root key name (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)"
${EndIf}
```

Comment: It's working fine. But i have doubts with using SID. Should i use S-1-5-32-545(Users) or S-1-1-0(Everyone)? What is the difference? If any new user added to windows login account then that user will be added in everyone or users?

Comment: Users is a group like Adminstrators is a group, Everyone depends on a setting in the registry but it is usually everyone excluding anonymous network share logons... Edit: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780850%28WS.10%29.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278259

Comment: Its not working when i checked through code. After adding this registry with access plugin i tried to change  the value by using a vb6 code (by using RegSetValueEx function) it didnt work.when run the code as run as administrator the registry changed.So what to do?So what is the use of setting permission for all users?

Comment: If you can see the permission change in regedit I don't really know how much more I can help...